# Illustrator CC 2020 Apple script (Popup "Select File Format")

Tags: applescript, adobe-illustrator

Since I updated my illustrator to CC 2020 (24.0) when I execute this command in apple script

```
set placedRef to make new placed item in layer "Layer1" of current document with properties {file path:pfilepath} without dialogs
```

Illustrator is displaying a popup : "Select a File Format to open file:" with 3 choices : Pixar, PNG or Targa.
Whatever I choose, nothing is inserted.

This exact same command works on illustrator CC 2019 and not popup is displayed.

Here is the full code to reproduce :

```
on run argv
    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        activate
        set user interaction level to never interact
        set placedRef to make new placed item in layer "ignore" of current document with properties {file path:item 1 of argv} without dialogs
    end tell
end run
```

Command example to run the script :

```
osascript test.scpt :Users:myusername:Download:test.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AI 2020 has changed the type of the `file path` property from a ‘file’ value to a POSIX path string, breaking compatibility with existing scripts ([more info](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/applescript-document-file-path-changed-format-in-2020/m-p/10758505)). Change your shell script to pass a POSIX path instead.